# How to Jquery each complete

Tags: jquery, each

I did not do the complete in `$.each()`. How this is done? Please help me.

```
$("element").each(function (i, v) {
        //No problem
    }, function () {
        //How to complete finished ??
        // alert(each finish);
    })
```

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are asking. Could you try rewording the problem statement?

Comment: What're you trying to achieve here? What does 'finish' refer to?

Comment: `.each` executes in the current thread. There is no asynchronicity happening. Just put the code after. I may be misunderstanding the question though; it's not very clear.

Comment: Using this package package https://github.com/ACFBentveld/Await

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To execute code after the `each` loop is over :

```
var count = $("element").length;

$("element").each(function (i) {
    // loop
    if (i+1 === count) {
        // this will be executed at the end of the loop
    }
});
```

Answer (score 19):

The `promise()` method is usually for AJAX, but it can be used with `each()` to achieve what you want:

```
$('.element').each(function (key, val) {
    console.log('Do something to each individual .element');
}).promise().done(function () { 
    console.log('Did things to every .element, all done.');
});
```

Comment: this doesn't work with `$.each()`. Error: `Uncaught TypeError: $.each(...).promise is not a function`.

Comment: it doesn't work, because it wasn't supposed to :)
if you want something to happen after $.each completes, just type right after it. $.each runs synchronously

Comment: @Manos But it's not ok, if you calling asynch scripts inside of each.

Comment: $.each() and element.each() are two different functions... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/   vs   https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 13):

You can simply use:

```
$.when( $.each() ).then(myFunc, failFunc);
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply check the index of the element, `i`, with the number of element at the end of the `.each()` loop. If it matches, then you are done with looping:

```
$('element').each(function (i, v) {
    // Do all the stuff here

    // Check if you are at the last item
    if ($('element').length === i+1) {
        // Code to execute when you are at the last item
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a late response. But this might come in handy
There is a package that does what you want.

```
var myObject = { // or your array
    1 : 'My first item',
    2 : 'My second item',
    3 : 'My third item'
}

Await.each(myObject, function(key, value){
     //your logic here
});

Await.done(function(){
    console.log('The loop is completely done');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    let control = $(".container").find("#result");
    const setPromise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        if(control.length){
            resolve("Not Problem...")
        }
        else{
            reject("WTF")
        }
    })

    setPromise.then(function(answer){
        console.log(answer)
    }).catch(function(answer){
        console.log(answer)
    })

})
```

Answer (score -6):

Just put what you want to do after the `.each` call. You're over thinking it.

```
$('.el').each(function () {
  $(this).something();
});
alert('Done');
```

Comment: putting it after the each will means the code will be executed even if there's no elements (and therefore no looping)

Comment: @Brewal OP wants a callback for when .each finished.

Comment: @Spokey I think I understood that

Comment: A callback would run when something is done, not if it's actually done something... if that makes sense.

Comment: Lol, ok I see what you guys are talking about, but yeah... It is hard to make sens when talking about callback on synchronous code ^^